# Replacement for D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated (Minimum Rebuild)

Tags: visual-studio, deprecated, deprecation-warning

As I recently upgraded Visual Studio from 2013 to 2019 I discovered that "Enable Minimal Rebuild" is deprecated. On compile I get `warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release`.
So I wonder why this is and if there is an replacement for this? When I disable "Minimal Rebuild" everytime I change some .cpp-file the whole project gets compiled which is pretty annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal rebuild was deprecated because it would sometimes not detect code changes correctly, causing very hard to diagnose link/runtime errors. I am not aware of any plans for a replacement. Even without minimal rebuild, VS shouldn't recompile files that weren't touched at all, so your issue with the entire project getting recompiled seems to be a separate one.